# Consider using varargs for methods or constructors

Tags: java

I have a function :

```
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    ...
}
```

And a tool about code style advise :

> Consider using varargs for methods or constructors which take an array the last parameter

How can I edit it??

Comment: I would probably ignore this advice, unless you want to let your method accept also values in form `bytesToHex((byte)1,(byte)2,(byte)3,(byte)4)`.

Comment: The tool is overeager.

Answer (score 2):

> [Doc Says,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) As an API designer, you should use them sparingly, only when the
>   benefit is truly compelling.

`vararg` can be represented by three dots `(...)` that's just not going to look good with `byte` at least IMHO. I suggest you to stick with `byte[]` as in most cases of programming we will have `byte[]` and not singular `byte` elements and you won't benefit anything with `varargs` in this particular case.

```
public static String bytesToHex(byte... bytes) {

}
```